# NodeJS middleware calling order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why `res.send("main page 2")` not overriding `res.send("main page 1")` when I request `localhost:3000` ?
While execucing this code in NodeJS only `console.log("midddleware")` is calling from `app.use` method but not `res.send`. I wonder why it works like that.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("main page 1")
})

app.use("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("main page 2")
    console.log("midddleware")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: The first one "caught" it. The second one catches anything the first one didn't catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely being tricked by the second request (for the favicon.ico) that the browser sends to your server.

Examining your code in more detail, here's what it will do:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("main page 1")
})

app.use("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("main page 2")
    console.log("midddleware")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

If you do a GET request for `/` to your server, Express matches routes in the order declared so the first one that will match is the `app.get()`.  It will send the response with `res.send("main page 1")` and because it does NOT call `next()`, all routing will be done and the `app.use("/", ...)` is never hit.

But, if you typed `http://localhost:3000` into the browser, that is not the only request that the browser will send to your server.   The browser will also send a request for `http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico` (the web site icon the browser likes to display).

That request will not be matched by the `app.get("/", ...)`, but because `app.use()` accepts partial matches (`app.get()` requires full matches only), the `/favicon.ico` request will be matched by `app.use("/", ..)` and you will see your `console.log("middleware")`.  You won't see the results of `res.send("main page 2")` because when the browser requested the favicon and got back some plain text, it will just ignore that is it clearly isn't the icon it was looking for.

If you modify your middleware to log the actual URL that is being requested, then all should be clear:

```
app.use("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("main page 2")
    console.log("midddleware", req.originalUrl);    // log the actual URL
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Middleware callback function examples](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples). It shows this example:

```js
var router = express.Router()
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next()
})
```

If you call `next()` in your first handler, the next one will get executed. But watch out – you can only call `res.send` once in a request-response cycle. The second one would throw an error – because the response was already sent.

See also [Writing Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) for more examples:

> The order of middleware loading is important: **middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.**
> If `myLogger` is loaded after the route to the root path, the request never reaches it and the app doesn’t print “LOGGED”, because the route handler of the root path terminates the request-response cycle.
> The middleware function `myLogger` simply prints a message, then passes on the request to the next middleware function in the stack by calling the `next()` function.